# how to mix existing types of data with simulated data created with classes on python 3

Tags: python, class, object, built-in

In my experiences I was trying to have a better understanding of how classes work in python 3 and I found out how amazing it can be. To make a few tests I created a entire class that simulates complex numbers in python 3. I developed ways to make new operations, way to represent the number, etc. Here it is the code (sorry but some parts were written in portuguese):

```
class imaginario:

def __init__(self, real = 0, imaginario = 0):
    self.parteReal = real
    self.parteImaginaria = imaginario

def real(self):
    return self.parteReal

def imaginario(self):
    return self.parteImaginaria

def __add__(self, outro):
    real = self.parteReal + outro.parteReal
    imaginaria = self.parteImaginaria + outro.parteImaginaria

    return imaginario(real, imaginaria)

def __sub__(self, outro):
    real = self.parteReal - outro.parteReal
    imaginaria = self.parteImaginaria - outro.parteImaginaria

    return imaginario(real, imaginaria)

def __mul__(self, outro):

    real = self.parteReal * outro.parteReal - self.parteImaginaria * outro.parteImaginaria
    imaginaria = self.parteReal * outro.parteImaginaria + self.parteImaginaria * outro.parteReal

    return imaginario(real, imaginaria)

def __truediv__(self, outro):

    divisor = outro.parteReal ** 2 + outro.parteImaginaria ** 2
    real = (self.parteReal * outro.parteReal + self.parteImaginaria * outro.parteImaginaria) / divisor
    imaginaria = (outro.parteReal * self.parteImaginaria - self.parteReal * outro.parteImaginaria) / divisor

    return imaginario(real, imaginaria)

def __repr__(self):

    number = ""

    if self.parteImaginaria != 0:
        if abs(self.parteImaginaria) == 1:
            number = number + "i"
        else:
            number = number + str(abs(self.parteImaginaria)) + "i"

        if self.parteImaginaria < 0:
            number = " - " + number
        else:
            number = " + " + number

    elif self.parteReal == 0:
        return "0"

    if self.parteReal == 0:
        return number
    else:
        return str(self.parteReal) + number

def __eq__(self, outro):
    return self.parteReal == outro.parteReal and self.parteImaginaria == outro.parteImaginaria

def isPure(self):
    return self.parteReal == 0

def isReal(self):
    return self.parteImaginaria == 0
```

The question I have is the following:

Is there a way I can make so I can make operation between integers and the way I represented complex numbers as for example:

```
>>>x = imaginario(2,3)
>>>x
2 + 3i
>>>x + 1
3 + 3i
```

Basically what I want to do is to implement a way so I can make operation with integer numbers and complex numbers.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to make your class compatible with the built-in numeric types, then it would be easiest to refractor your own class to work with the interface. Note, `x = 42` now try printing `x.real, x.imag` So, to work *seemlessly*, I'd use those attribute names. Otherwise, you'll have to handle the logic of checking the types somehow, and not rely on duck-typing.

Comment: Also, I would *highly* suggest following Python style conventions, i.e. use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`, don't use getters like `def real(self): return self.parteReal`, just use plain attribute access. If you need to control the access, use a `property`.